# Error in return function in bool data type

Tags: flutter

recently, I update my flutter sdk and directly found out that some of my code get error. I have already fixed some of them, but I can not solve this one.

Here is some part of my code:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  TextEditingController txtuserid = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtpass = TextEditingController();
  String getUserName = '';

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void showInSnackBar(String value) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(value)));
  }

  bool check = false;
  List<Users> resultUsers;

  Future insertUserLogs(String userid) async {
    var url = 'https://eucarissa-soft.com/mg/record_login.php';
    await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {"UserID": userid});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Image.asset(
              'images/abstract.png',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 300,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 40, right: 40),
            child: Image.asset(
              'images/logo_mgs.png',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 170,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
          ListView(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 280,
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[800],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 20, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 5),
                      child: TextField(
                        style: myStyleWhite,
                        controller: txtuserid,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          labelText: "User ID",
                          labelStyle: myStyleWhite,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 5, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 5),
                      child: TextField(
                        obscureText: true,
                        style: myStyleWhite,
                        controller: txtpass,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          labelText: "Password",
                          labelStyle: myStyleWhite,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    (check)
                        ? SpinKitFadingCircle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            size: 45,
                          )
                        : Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 5, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 20),
                            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, //350
                              height: 50, //50
                              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: abu2tua,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                ),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'LOGIN',
                                      style: myStyleBigBold,
                                    ),
                                    Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)
                                  ],
                                ),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                                  setState(() {
                                    check = true;
                                  });
                                  if (txtuserid.text.trim().length == 0 ||
                                      txtpass.text.trim().length == 0) {
                                    showInSnackBar(
                                        'Please fill user id and password!');
                                    setState(() {
                                      check = false;
                                    });
                                  } else {
                                    await UsersService.getPosts(
                                            txtuserid.text, txtpass.text)
                                        .then((value) => resultUsers = value);
                                    getUserName = resultUsers[0].username;
                                    if (resultUsers[0].username != 'No Data') {
                                      setState(() {
                                        check = true;
                                      });
                                      userID = txtuserid.text.toUpperCase();
                                      await insertUserLogs(txtuserid.text);
                                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  HomePage()));
                                    } else {
                                      setState(() {
                                        check = false;
                                      });
                                      showInSnackBar(
                                          'User id and password didnt match!');
                                    }
                                  }

                                  return check;
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I found the error in the end of this code in : return check;
it says "The return type 'bool' isn't a 'Future', as required by the closure's context."

Can anyone help me please..

Well actually I found error also in this code:

```
List<Users> resultUsers;
```

it says "Non-nullable instance field 'resultUsers' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'."

Thank you..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your `build` method.

Comment: Follow the [migration guide](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Answer (score 0):

In this string:

```
'User id and password didn't match!'
```

You have an apostrophe (`'`) inside a string that use single quotes. This confuses the analyzer (and make the program won't compile, in fact, it's an error). You can either escape the apostrophe by using the escape character `\`:

```dart
'User id and password didn\'t match!'
```

Or change the string to use double quotes instead:

```dart
"User id and password didn't match!"
```

This is as demonstrated in the official Dart site: [`Strings`](https://dart.dev/language/built-in-types#strings)

---

It seems like you're migrating from a non null-safety to a null-safety version of Dart. You can follow this [migration guide](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide).

Comment: I have already read the article, but can not find the solution for my code. sorry I'm newbie..

Comment: Basically run `dart migrate` and follow the instructions. I didn't give details on how to do it because you probably have more than one thing (besides the late variable issue) that need to be migrated

Comment: I have already execute dart migrate, but "migrate" doesn't know by flutter.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Users> resultUsers=[];
```

**or**

```
late  List<Users> resultUsers;
```

> `late` -->used to indicate that a non-nullable variable will be
> initialized later in the code

**or**

```
 List<Users> ? resultUsers;
```

> `the question mark` means that this list  can possibly be null and
> flutter will allow you to assign null to it

"**In**  `onPressed function` , trying to remove `return check` may solve the issue."

Comment: Ah ok, it works.. But I haven't tried to run the apps, because I still got problem while running to emulator.. but thanks anyway for you answer..

Answer (score 0):

> "Non-nullable instance field 'resultUsers' must be initialized. Try
> adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that
> initializes it, or mark it 'late'."

```
List<Users> resultUsers
```

**Is an array which has been declared, but not initialized.**

Referencing a declared but unassigned variable will throw as it's trying to access something which doesn't yet exist.

To fix this, initialize the array:

```
List<Users> resultUsers = [];
```

> I found the error in the end of this code in : return check; it says
> "The return type 'bool' isn't a 'Future', as required by the closure's
> context."

Flutter's [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html)'s onPressed property is of type `VoidCallback`,
which is just a typdef for `void Function()`.

`void` indicates that the closure expects **no return**, so the function should not return anything.

If you remove the `async`, the IDE should give you an indication that nothing is expected to be returned.

Official docs for [functions](https://dart.dev/language/functions)

Comment: ok, thank you for your response and explanation.. it works as you wrote..